# Are there theories that can predict the Yukawa couplings?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

In the standard model, the Yukawa couplings, hence the masses of the fermions, are free parameters and are only determined by experiment. Are there beyond the SM theories that can "predict" the Yukawa couplings? I would appreciate any suggestion about review articles too.

Comment: There are many such theories (I probably have at least 30 bookmarked in my browser). None have wide acceptance. Not sure if an annotated bibliography of that literature would be within the scope of Physics.SE.

Comment: I keep a sporadically updated raw list of such articles at https://dispatchesfromturtleisland.blogspot.com/p/physics-literature-regarding.html

Answer (score 0):

One such theory that I have come across is the [Framed Standard Model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05472), which posits that the fermion mass matrix is generated by a "frame field", dual to SU(3) colour. I have not seen any evaluation of this theory by physicists other than the authors, however.